# pInvokeStackImbalance MDA Warning and how to turn it off or fix it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

```
    [DllImport( "zlib32" )]
    private static extern ZLibError compress2( 
                byte[] dest,
                ref int destLength, 
                byte[] source, 
                int sourceLength, 
                ZLibQuality quality 
            );
```

every time I call this I get an MDA warning telling me the stack is imbalanced, which is a nightmare for debugging. I want to either turn this warning off, or fix the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This MDA raised to tell you that you have a problem with parameters type you are using for PInvoke call. Generally, it is **very bad idea to turn it off** since it warns about problem in your code and imbalanced stack leads to errors (sometimes hard to find) in future.

Usually, common mistake is selected matching for unmanaged type with managed one.

In your case, original defininition (I take a look to [zlib125.zip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/index.html)):

```
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT compress2 OF((Bytef *dest,   uLongf *destLen,
                                  const Bytef *source, uLong sourceLen,
                                  int level));
```

which can be traslated to if library was compiled with 64-bit support for `unsigned long`:

```
static int compress2(
    byte[] dest,
    ref ulong destLength,
    byte[] source,
    ulong sourceLength,
    int level)
```

Ensure `ZLibQuality`enumeration is based on int. Probably, your error is usage **int** instead of **ulong** for both lengths.

As stated David Heffernan there are plenty other reasons to fail to find exact one give us link to library actually used for development if you still want to know.

- traditional compilation original library with Visual C++ will result you get library with 32-bit support only, so original definition you provided in question is valid unless `ZLibQuality` enumeration is not `int` based
- maybe you try to use library compiled for other calling convention such as `cdecl` instead of `stdcall`
- maybe you try to use modified library where `compress2` function takes additional parameters.

We can find whats wrong when we can see exact library you are using.

> `long` or `unsigned long` [usually 32-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Int64) under Windows and mapped to `int` or `uint` respectively. Since you have troubles with original declaration I assumed that maybe you are using specific library with 64-bit support. Thanks to David Heffernan to point me makes my notice clearly.

You can use folowing resourses as reference:

- [A wiki for .NET developers](http://www.pinvoke.net/) - PInvoke.net is primarily a wiki, allowing developers to find, edit and add PInvoke* signatures, user-defined types, and any other information related to calling Win32 and other unmanaged APIs from managed code
- [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120)

/Offtopic:

Why do you use you own implementation with self bindings to library? You can use:

- [DotNetZip - Zip and Unzip in C#, VB, any .NET language](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) - DotNetZip is an easy-to-use, FAST, FREE class library and toolset for manipulating zip files or folders. Zip and Unzip is easy: with DotNetZip, .NET applications written in VB, C# - any .NET language - can easily create, read, extract, or update zip files. For Mono or MS .NET.
- or ready to use 7-zip bindings: [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) - Managed 7-zip library written in C# that provides data (self-)extraction and compression (all 7-zip formats are supported). It wraps 7z.dll or any compatible one and makes use of LZMA SDK.

Comment: it's an opensource proyect I'm expanding on [www.runuo.com] and this is how they implemented it years ago when they started the proyect. It's used to send compressed info from the server to the client, and I suspect using something else wouldn't be supported by the client? [which is not contained by the open source proyect]

Comment: You can easily use DotNetZip, it is managed compression library, based on ZLIB so it produces compatible results. Also DotNetZip is open source project just check its page. I don't see any troubles to switch.

Comment: As I understand it, a C `unsigned long` is 32 bits on all Windows platforms, so I don't think your explanation hangs together. `int` is certainly wrong though because it is signed. I think it should be `uint`.

Comment: @David, yes `long` or `unsigned long` *usually* is 32-bit in C/C++ and 64-bit in .NET but it really depend on compiler and platform. Try to look to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Int64, it really depends on what and how library actually was compiled. Since OP does not provide link to used library I just guess what can be go wrong. I'll update my answer to make things clear, thank to point out.

Comment: @nick the platform is windows and the language is C so it's 32 bits.

Comment: @David, it can easily overrided even on Windows platform. By default library uses `typedef unsigned long  uLong` but if you noticed everywhere in definitions it uses `uLong` so it can be easily substitute this type with `long long` or e.g. `MKL_LONG` and compile with Intel C++ compiler targets to x64. Of course it has a sense only for custom library built but it is possible even on Windows.

Comment: @David, ok :) Just want you know that I make zlib library with such support myself long time ago to give us opportunity to handle files large than 4 GB and uses 64-bit integers to handle lengths. It pretty simple to do. So I talk about real cases not theoretical one. Thanks for all suggestions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

The stack imbalance is because you have mis-matching calling conventions or mis-matching function declarations. I'd be very surprised if `zlib32` was using `stdcall` calling convention. Surely that uses `cdecl`. I'd want to see your C++ declaration of that function before giving firmer advice.

Leave the warning on because it's finding bugs in your code, and fix the mis-matches, whatever they are.

Comment: If OP use original zLib it has `#define ZEXPORT WINAPI` `#define ZEXTERN extern __declspec(dllexport)`, and as you surely know `#define WINAPI      __stdcall`. So by default on Win32 compiler will choose stdcall calling convention.

Comment: @Nick I'm not familiar with details of zlib as you appear to be. Your answer contains lots of sound advice, especially the advice not to re-invent the wheel. The main point of my answer is the second paragraph!

Comment: I absolutely agree with that. MDAs can save a lot of time on debugging hard to find errors so turn it off is very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a real issue here, but I usually have to disable all Managed Debugging Assistants every now and then, since some of these magically get enabled.  Be sure to check Debug | Exceptions node, then **expand** the Managed Debugging Assistants and make sure every one of these is disabled.

**EDIT:**  You will have better luck replacing the P/Invoke with a C++/CLI wrapper that you create for `compress2`.

Comment: P/Invoke isn't that hard and doing so removes a layer. That's attractive to me.

Comment: Certainly true, but makes debugging more difficult.

Comment: Switching off these stack imbalance warnings sounds like it would make debugging even hard in my view.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll give MDA another try, perhaps they're much improved in VS2010 than from previous versions.  I've never had any use for MDA in VS2008 and earlier, simply seemed like a broken mechanism.